# 2 displays detected on ThinkPad T400

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, thinkpad, laptop-display

I want to ask if somebody know why there are 2 internal displays detected on my ThinkPad T400 on Win 8.1. I don't remember if it detect 2 displays also on other systems but I think yes.

It brings a problem of switching between displays when I have external monitor also connected and press Win+P and switch for example to Extend monitors.. It extend that *"2 internal"* displays and just ignore the external monitor.

And really I don't have mutant laptop with 2 displays.

Here are some screenshots:

In screen resolution manager:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gj6qE78.png]

In device manager:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/bxn2Cx1.png]

Comment: If you click the Identify button, what do you see?

Comment: Ok, now it is stranger than before, when I check this. Now I have connected External monitor (3), and two internal displays (2, 1), and all displays are extended so I have 3, 2 and 1 extended. I click Identify and just on external monitor are shown 3 and 1 numbers. So I disconnected display 2 (that which I usually use as my laptop display) apply and there is physically only external screen active now but Identify always shows 3&1. When I disconnect d.1 and extend d.2 to main external mon.3 as usually I can see physically screen on ext. and also on laptop and identify showing 3&2 on external.

Comment: 1) In Device Manager, how many display adapters are shown? How many should there be? 2) (Make sure you have everything necessary backed up before trying this.) I would just uninstall the second occurrence of the ThinkPad Display from Device Manager and see what happens.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have 2 display adapters, one is "internal" (Mobile intel 4 series...) and one is "external" (ATI Mobility Radeon...) And yes if I double-click on one ThinkPad display there in field Location is: "on ATI Mobility Radeon..." and when I click on that other there is location "on Mobile Intel...". I uninstalled that display, nothing happend, so restarted and I wasn't able to get in my PC. There was just blank screen and cursor when I move mouse. I had to restor system. I like this system but IMHO Win 8. is really retarded when talking about compatibility :(

Comment: @AndrewMorton to end my thoughts I have problems from very beginning of using it. I couldn't install my video driver for ATI Mobility Radeon so I manually downloaded package, which Win didn't installed so I manually installed just driver through Dev.Manager.. To my other question posted few weeks ago that often Win boot stuck and nothing happen but I have to hard shut down my laptop holding power button and than reboot again.. Don't you think it is annoying? For an IT student working almost everyday on it it really is and nobody can help me yet..

Comment: It is also strange that I have now display 2 extended to external monitor 3 and when I press Win+P there is shown that I am using option second screen only. When I go for Extend, it start to ignore ext.m. 3 and Extend 1 and 2 displays.. It driving me crazy when I can't use keyboard shortcuts and but have to use mouse to do it on several clicks through screen resolution manager..

Answer (score 2):

Had trouble with the Lenovo T400 I just received and the only way to get the icons to display on the desktop was to Set the ***Config>Display*** settings in the BIOS to ***Discrete Graphics*** and set the ***OS Detection for Switchable Graphics*** to ***Disabled***.  It was acting like Windows 10 does not allow Switchable Graphics.  When the *OS Detection for Switchable Graphics* was ***Enabled*** it would change the ***Dedicated Graphics*** setting to ***Switchable Graphics*** and no icons would be displayed on the desktop - nothing worked.  By the way, Windows 10 works great on this Laptop!

Comment: For me it also looked like Win10 has no problem on my T400 but when I tried to do something with switchable graphics it just failed and then I returned to Win 7. For me, if one thing not work, I just can´t say it work :(

Answer (score 1):

If you select Switchable Graphics in your BIOS, it's working this way on Windows 8.1

I can't find any working solutions for switchable graphics for the T400 under Win 8.1, there will be no driver update, i think we should be living with that.

I changed the settings in the BIOS to Dedicated graphics (you can for the internal too), this way it is working. If you will change for the other graphic card, you must restart.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I can try and think you're right but this should be managed with some software for switchable graphics where I can use some settings for when internal graphic card is used and when dedicated.. however, if I'm right I think Win 8.1 do not support such software for example from ATI.. But, you get me enthusiasm to get in it again to search for som esolution in this way.. I will post reply when I get something :) Happy new year to you :)

Comment: Hey, I have working switchable graphics on my T400 with Win8.1 now. I posted question to lenovo comunity forums and there are some nice answers which helped me. Look here: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/T400-Windows-8-1-support-stop/td-p/1862387/page/2 and on site 2 find link for working switchable graphics by user ColonelONeill. You must install it first before all AMD drivers or software. After that you install newest package downloaded from AMD support site. Now I live on Win8.1 WITHOUT updates of OS and devices by Microsoft and it looks like it works

Comment: To end my thoughts, now there is no more 2 displays detected and everything working fine. Please If you use T400 with Win8.1 how it works for you? I had to turn off all updates by Microsoft to make it work for me but I'm still in fear that my system crashes and after boot my screen will be blank (see my other question here on Superuser http://superuser.com/questions/868195/thinkpad-t400-and-windows-8-1-compatibility-and-support). Please let me know how your laptop works with this system and how you make it work.