# ThinkPad T400 and Windows 8.1 "compatibility and support"

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, windows-update, thinkpad

firstly, it's really hard to make title on this but I'll try to explain below.

This problem occurs for some time but I think, not from very beginning of using Windows 8.1 on my ThinkPad T400. When I start my laptop, it boot and then there is blank screen with just mouse cursor moving when I move with mouse. When I press Win+P blank panel appears on the right side just as normal when I want to switch screens but it is totally blank. And only one window can be seen when I press 5x Shift Sticky keys window appears. And that's all. I tried to restore system by restore point - in the past it was working but now that doesn't help me anymore. Here you should see how it looks: http://youtu.be/8xv7Cf7MZHk

I think it should be Windows updates but don't know why. I had set Win updates to manual install because I hated it when it runs updates and I was in hurry. So this week when I manually updated OS blank screen appears, I had to reinstall my win because there was nothing to do. And I thought, that Automatic updates will solve my problem because maybe it is not good when there are very old, old and new updates installed in one time. First update, was fine, everything runs fine. Yesterday, after 3-4 days from OS install blank screen appears after start after updates. I was really angry. I reinstalled OS 3 times during 8 days, don't imagine my anger.

Today I reinstalled it again and set OS to not download any updates. Hope it will solve it but anyway, I will have non updated OS.

Does anybody know what should I do? Does Lenovo stop supporting my model on laptop? Does Lenovo not support Windows 8.1? Has Microsoft bugs in their updates? I wonder why this is happening to me. I have Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit from DreamSpark. I have all drivers updated, no malware, no viruses. Anyway it is nearly impossible to find drivers on my laptop for Win 8.1.
to the end no one of my friends which are using ThinkPads with Win 8.1 have simillar problems.

To the end, I don't want to buy another laptop, and don't want to stop using Win 8.1. But I want to be sure to not happen  things like this to me. I use it almost everyday and really I need my laptop for study and need it to be reliable.

Comment: Lenovo stopped supporting your device awhile ago.

Comment: @Ramhound So what that means for me? I should put my perfectly working laptop aside and buy something supported? I don't know how it can influence functioning of my laptop. It's up to Microsoft, their system and updates, how Lenovo support relate on it? Ok, drivers are one think but I have all drivers and I update just OS, and then it falls down and is not running properly anymore.

Comment: Its up to Lenovo to support drivers for newer versions of Windows.  Windows without supported drivers will present problems like you describe.  It appears the machine came with `Windows 7` which is fully supported on the hardware you have.  I am not saying all hope is lost, but one of your questions was, does Lenovo not even support `Windows 8.1`?  The answer to that question is **NO**

Comment: I turned off all updates by Microsoft, that means OS and also Hardware. Now it looks like it is working fine, but I'm still in fear that it will crash again. But hope it won't. I also installed switchable graphics driver for T400 for Win8. See link on site 2 of this thread I created on lenovo comunity forums http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/T400-Windows-8-1-support-stop/td-p/1862387/page/2

Answer (score -1):

Definitelly I installed **`Windows 7`** Pro 64 bit and now it is working just perfectly. I downloaded System update directly from Lenovo support site and it installed everything without problems, I also have my system updated and my system never crashed from that time.

So If anybody has a problem with old ThinkPads running with Win8/8.1 go back to Win7 and probably it will work perfectly again as ThinkPads usually do :)

To the end, I tried almost everything but nothing helped me to keep my system stable - updating, not-updating, not-updating device drivers by Microsoft..